# Can't convert array to CSV

Tags: javascript

I have an array `selectedWorkCentres` that looks like this

```
Array[0]
5N5-4-E: true
EDI-4-E: true
length: 0__proto__: Array[0]
```

I've tried `selectedWorkCentres.join()`

I expected

```
"5N5-4-E,EDI-4-E"
```

but always get back

```
""
```

EDIT: this is the code used to generate the array

```
var grid = e.sender;
            var items = grid.items();
            items.each(function (idx, row) {
                var idValue = grid.dataItem(row).get(idField);
                if (row.className.indexOf("k-state-selected") >= 0) {
                    selectedOrders[idValue] = true;
                } else if (selectedOrders[idValue]) {
                    delete selectedOrders[idValue];
                }
            });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please run `console.log(JSON.stringify(selectedWorkCentres))` and replace your array code with the result? That way it will be in a format one can use to try and recreate the issue.

Comment: Sorry it just returns []

Comment: There are better structures to hold string keys: Sets, Maps or plain old objects.

Comment: Well, that means there are no entries in the array. What you've done is add properties to an array. Show us the code that you used to generate that variable.

Comment: If it returns [] then you are getting right answer.

Comment: `Array[0]` Means the array is empty it has no items, your expected contents look to object properties also. You should show how you're populating the array because you have other underlying issues here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Object.keys` to extract non-integer keys from array.

```js
const arr = []

arr['5N5-4-E'] = true
arr['EDI-4-E'] = true

console.log(Object.keys(arr).join())
```

But keep in mind that the order in this case is not guaranteed. Also there are better structures to use arbitrary keys: [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one because i think join() does not work with associative arrays

```
Object.keys(selectedWorkCentres).join();
```